# laravel8 appending value & name on a store followed by update action (dropdown form)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fairly new to programming, I already developed a bad application, but its working in php 5, with some other languages. Now I'm investing in Laravel 8 which follows better security practices to deployments on safe ambients, online, with the composer install and the tokens etc... I'm happy I'm doing this, now my doubt is this:

I have a mileage tracking app and I have the drivers who will fill the car travel form on the app. The difficult thing in the form is just grabbing the km's at the end of the travel. I've done it in php5 first application and I'm trying to replicate the way on Laravel 8, so it's like this:

on opening the form, users have a dropdown with the car plates of the cars. and when they select one, it loads the car's current kms, and the only thing they will have to type is the kms in which the ride ended with (the ending kms). On submitting the form, it will have to update the table cars, (it has two tables (cars and travels) on the travels table it will store everything the current kms had, and the end kms at the end. Afterwards it proceeds to a update on cars table on the current kms so it can load them on the next form filling. I'm struggling on Laravel8 to do this as well. I'll show an image of the dropdown I have.

[image]

and some code:

```
//create .blade
<select name="quilometragem" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
 @foreach($viaturas as $item)
<option value="{{ $item['quilometragem'] }}">{{ $item->matricula  }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this car has the following km: " + x;
    }
</script>
//form controller
public function create(Request $request,Viaturas $matricula)
    {
        
        $viaturas = Viaturas::all();
        
        $matricula = Viaturas::find($matricula);
       
        return view('admin.formulario.create', compact('viaturas'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request,Viaturas $matricula)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'quilometragem' => 'required',
            'matricula' => 'required',
            'perguntadois' => 'required|gt:quilometragem',
        ]);
        $formulario = new Formulario;
        $formulario->quilometragem = $request->input('quilometragem');
        $formulario->perguntadois = $request->input('perguntadois');
        $formulario->matricula = $request->input('matricula');
        $formulario->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Formulario Added Successfully');
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4bOK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmaj2.png)

[dropanddie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb1KE.png)

Comment: I know I have no name on the select referring to car plate(matricula) but i have instead the quilometragem(current km's), i think this can be solved with an array split or something like that i'm just not sure on what i should do to do the store and update at the same time if someone can help would be glad

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
In controller:

```
public function create(Request $request,Viaturas $matricula)
{
    
    $data['viaturas'] = Viaturas::all();
    
    $data['matricula'] = Viaturas::find($matricula);
   
    return view('admin.formulario.create', $data);
}

public function store(Request $request,Viaturas $matricula)
{
    $request->validate([
        'quilometragem' => 'required',
        'matricula' => 'required',
        'perguntadois' => 'required|gt:quilometragem',
    ]);

    $data = [
        'quilometragem' =>$request->input('quilometragem'),
       'perguntadois' => $request->input('perguntadois'),
        'matricula' =>$request->input('matricula')
    ];

    Formulario::create($data);
    $viaturas = Viaturas::find($matricula);
    if($viaturas){
        $matricula->update([
            'quilometragem' =>$request->input('perguntadois')
        ]);

    }else{
        echo "No Viaturas found for this ".$matricula;
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Formulario Added Successfully');
}
```

In view:

```
    <select name="quilometragem" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
 @foreach($viaturas as $item)
<option value="{{ $item['quilometragem'] }}">{{ $item->matricula  }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the answere, i tried now, it's working well.. now how should i do so that when a form is submitted it will update the current "quilometragem" from viaturas table?

Comment: I did not get your question, Do you want to update?

Comment: please vote my answer if it have solved your problem.

Comment: abdullah your solution done the same i already had... wich was load the current km's in the dropdown , what i want is the following: i have two tables (viaturas & formulario) in viaturas table i store current km's , so... when a user fills a form it stores on formulario the questions, and on "perguntadois" it will ask for the end of travel km's, that km's have to be inserted in formulario and update "viaturas" current km's so that when next form is opened it will load in the dropdown the last travel end km's.

Comment: I dont get your question. Do you want to add km to 'formulario' and also want to update '"viaturas' based on the last km of  'formulario'?

Comment: my question is this: i am fetching the current km's from viaturas table of each car, and on user selecting one from the dropdown it will appear the current km's , i want now is to, on the form the user will have to input on "perguntadois" the end of ride km's, after submit, what has to happen is, store the form details on "formulario" table and update selected car on viaturas with "perguntadois" on the quilometragem field, each car on viaturas has the "matricula" and "quilometragem"

Comment: can you share your database screenshot and their relationship?

Comment: i edited my question with the prints of the tables

Comment: I have updated my answer on my understanding so far I hope it solve your problem.

Comment: i tried inserting, looks like the code it's correct but it doesnt submit... something small is missing here xD because almost everything is here already

Comment: oky please DD 'dd($matricula);' in your controller store function and then share the result. here

Comment: i've edited the question with the dropanddie print :)

Comment: But there is no data in your request.

Comment: in viaturas controller i got store like this:
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $viaturas = new Viaturas;
        $viaturas->matricula = $request->input('matricula');
        $viaturas->marca = $request->input('marca');
        $viaturas->ac = $request->input('ac');
        $viaturas->lugares = $request->input('lugares');
        $viaturas->quilometragem = $request->input('quilometragem');
        $viaturas->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Viaturas Added Successfully');
    }

Comment: You want to store new data in one table and update some of the data in other table so you have to fist store that new data and then update the other table in the same function.

Comment: exatcly it's that..

Comment: i've done it in php5 but with laravel ... it's not being easy as well...

Comment: `dd($request->all());` at begining of store function and then submit your data. and share the the result

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "F2VFxPXzLz5c2JrId7SfZmZ5xnG8LH3q69BE8K3R"
  "_method" => "POST"
  "quilometragem" => "2"
  "perguntadois" => "3"
]

Comment: but there is no selected car to update? you should also pass 'car_id' that we can find that car and update info for it.

Comment: i've put the id on the model, on the request validate, and on $data array on store, i'm not being able to debug and do what you've just asked me to do. not that i'm lazy but im really lost here xDD